# font face not working in ie

Tags: internet-explorer, css, font-face

I have created a html layout and using css3 `@font-face`. Here is my code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyriadProRegular';
    src: url('myriad.eot');
    src: url('myriad.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('myriad.woff') format('woff'),
         url('myriad.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('myriad.svg#MyriadProRegular') format('svg');
}
```

and i am using

```
font-family: 'MyriadProRegular';
```

it's work in all browsers accept IE. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I can't recommend Font Squirrel enough for this. Just run through their Font Face generator and you'll get code that will work in IE. If you're missing a font file type it even makes that for you. It's saved me a lot of time in the past and I can't recommend it enough.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

This is from Font Squirrel and works cross browser:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'NimbusSanConD-Lig';
    src: url('fonts/228BFB_1_0.eot');
    src: url('fonts/228BFB_1_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/228BFB_0_0.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/228BFB_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are **svg**, **woff** and **eot** even (supported) font types? I'm pretty sure .svg is not and I've never heard of .woff and .eot.. Just a truetype should work in all browswers. (I'm not sure about Macintosh though)

the way font-face always works for me:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:alba;
    src:url(alba.ttf);
}
```

So no quotes used here. What I'd suggest to also try for your case, is to do it like

```
@font-face {
        font-family:Myriad Pro Regular;/* note the whitespaces, I believe this is what the font itself is called (not the filename) */
        src:url(myriad.ttf);
    }
```

Make sure you always mind the difference between uppercase and lowercase letters! If the font file is called *Myriad.ttf* while you type *myriad.ttf*, it might not work in some browser(version)s.

Comment: .eot is needed for IE. Microsoft being difficult again.

Comment: Not as far as I know but worth checking. I think they've always done it.

Comment: I've checked and my way seems to work just fine in FF, IE, Chrome and Safari :)

Comment: I have IE9 installed. Other versions can't be reliably checked

Comment: True. IE Tester is spotty at best and the other versions mode in IE9 are nothing like the actual browsers. I've had to run a virtual machine for IE 7 and 8 (IE 6 can go to hell). I'm pretty sure your code won't run in anything < 9.

Comment: What is, according to you, the best software/site to simulate this (preferably for all major browsers)? I'd greatly appreciate it if you could share a link! :)

Comment: The only truly reliable way is to run the actual browser. A virtual PC might seem like overkill but until they release standalones for Windows 7 it's the best I can think of.

Comment: But what is your best bet, even though not fully reliable? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by 'standalones'? Do you mean non-official browsers that work in the same way as a(n) (specific) older version of a certain browser?

Comment: IE Tester is the best of a bad bunch. If you're on Windows XP you can get IE7 and IE8 Stand Alone versions (http://ie7-standalone.en.softonic.com/)